# How to fix WSOD issue complaining about Guzzle?

Tags: composer-php, guzzle, drupal-8, wsod

After enabling some modules on a Drupal 8 development in progress I got a WSOD. Debugging information threw the following issue:

> Fatal error: Interface 'GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueueInterface' not found in /var/www/html/galtane-clean/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php on line 13

I tried to isolate the problem causing module by enabling the modules one by one on a backup of my database (pre-problem), but the error reappeared immediately after the first try. Then I un-installed this module and the problem was still present leading me to believe it has nothing to do with the modules in the first place, but rather with a process that accompanying the enabling of modules inside of Drupal.

That's as far as my debugging skills reach, apart from Googling, which gave me very little clues. [This is one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963487/composer-autoloader-not-loading-guzzlehttp-clientinterface) I found and I tried updating Composer with no effect. If anyone has ideas about this, or could point me in the right direction, would love to hear about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove all vendors and install them again. Seems that you have corrupted dependency of `guzzlehttp/promise`.